# how do i make my selection of fonts apply to a textbox

Tags: html, css, text, fonts

I have created a drop down list with several font families. Right below the list I've added a `textbox`. How do I make my selection apply to the `textbox`?

The idea is that customers have the option to engrave their name and should be able to see in the `textbox` what their name looks like with the font they've selected.

Answer (score 0):

You could try JavaScript.
Define a variable that receives the input from your list and uses it to determine the font with which it will be written in the text box

```
let fontInput = document.querySelector ("#idOfYourInput");
let fontstyle = fontInput.value;
```

Then you must assign fontstyle to be the value which determines the font you will use when writing in the textbox.